# duplicate items on a list- inserting output after the second item

Tags: python

I've got a list of names of people entering the hotel.

- If it's their first entry, the program should say ("welcome", name)
- If it's their second entry, the program should say ("good to see you again", name).

My problem is that the second greeting isn't in the right order.
How do i insert the second greeting after the second time the name appears?

With

```
enter = ["David", "Orly", "Neta", "Peleg", "Carol", "Ezra", "Irina", 
         "Orly", "Shir", "Neta", "Sheli", "Neta", "Ezra", "Yosi"]
```

my expected output would be:

```
Welcome  David
Welcome  Orly
Welcome  Neta
Welcome  Peleg
Welcome  Carol
Welcome  Ezra
Welcome  Irina
Good to see you again Orly
Welcome  Shir
Good to see you again Neta
Welcome  Sheli
Good to see you again Neta
Good to see you again Ezra
Welcome  Yosi
```

Here is my code:

```
enter = ["David", "Orly", "Neta", "Peleg", "Carol", "Ezra", "Irina", "Orly", "Shir", "Neta", "Sheli", "Neta", "Ezra", "Yosi"]

i = 0

for i in enter:
    print ("welcome", i)
    if enter.count(i)>1:
        print("good to see you again",i)
```

And my current, wrong output:

```
welcome David
welcome Orly
good to see you again Orly
welcome Neta
good to see you again Neta
welcome Peleg
welcome Carol
welcome Ezra
good to see you again Ezra
welcome Irina
welcome Orly
good to see you again Orly
welcome Shir
welcome Neta
good to see you again Neta
welcome Sheli
welcome Neta
good to see you again Neta
welcome Ezra
good to see you again Ezra
welcome Yosi
```

Answer (score 2):

`count` will tell you how many times they are in the list, but not whether this is the first time.  I suggest you add people to a Set as you see them, and then you can check if they have been seen before by checking whether they are in the Set.

Answer (score 2):

You count if a name is more than once in the whole list, not only in the part of entrance events, which "happened" up to now.
Besides that, in case someone's count is >1 you print both, 'welcome' *and* 'good to see you again'.

This way it works better:

```
for i, name in enumerate(enter):
    if name in enter[:i]:
        print("Good to see you again", name)
    else:
        print ("Welcome", name)
```